# Escaping Dash Character in batch file using Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, file-io, batch-file, escaping, command-prompt

I am working on a simple program in which a file containing computer names is read by a C++ file as seen in the following:

```
//Previously, the file containing names was opened and 
//getline() is in use to read each line
//note that 'line' is a string containing the current line being read 

string comp = lower(trim(line.erase(0, 2)));

//lower converts to lowercase (for later in the program) and 
//trim trims the beginning and ends of the string.  
//I have erased the first two characters, since they contain two \'s
ofstream bat;
bat.open("names_get.bat");
if (bat.is_open()) {                                     
    bat << "wmic.exe /node:"+comp+" ComputerSystem Get UserName >CompNames.txt";
    bat.close();
}
```

This all functions perfectly well.  However, I am encountering a problem when this batch file is executed using shellexecute.  My problem is that the command prompt is encountering computer names such as "Owner-PC" and taking the - as a parameter, resulting in an invalid global switch error.  Can someone please point me in the correct direction concerning how to escape the dash in such an event.  Thank you, and sorry for the long question!

Comment: good question, i'm also curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should surround your `comp`name with `"`Like

```
 wmic.exe /node:"prefix-suffix" ComputerSystem Get Username
```

So add `\"` in your code and it should work

```
if (bat.is_open()) {                                     
    bat << "wmic.exe /node:\""+comp+"\" ComputerSystem Get UserName >CompNames.txt";
    bat.close();
}
```